# Exclude list values from data frame column and add the result to the data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

If I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd 
dic = {'1':['sport','news'], '2':['news'],'3':['science']}
df = pd.Series(dic)
df = pd.DataFrame(df,columns = ['cat'])
```

and the following list:

```
all_catgs= ['sport','news','science','art','business']
```

I wan't to add a new column to this dataframe(df) that derived from all_catgs list excluding the value of df['cat'] columns for each row.

for example the result should be like:

```
             cat   all_exclude_cat
1  [sport, news]   ['science', 'art', 'business']
2         [news]   ['sport', 'science', 'art', 'business']
3      [science]   ['sport', 'news', 'art', 'business']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [Python sets](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) for this:

```
df['all_exclude_cat'] = df.cat.apply(lambda cat: list(set(all_catgs) - set(cat)))
```

The result then looks like this:

```
             cat                  all_exclude_cat
1  [sport, news]         [science, art, business]
2         [news]  [sport, science, art, business]
3      [science]     [news, sport, art, business]
```

Comment: df['all_exclude_cat']=df.cat.apply(lambda x: ','.join([ i for i in  all_catgs  if i not in x]))

Answer (score 0):

Because the `apply` method doesn't change the `df` in-place, you can use a simple `lambda` with list-comprehension to create a new column:

```
df["all_exclude_cat"] = df.cat.apply(lambda x: [i for i in all_catgs if i not in x])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
             cat                  all_exclude_cat
1  [sport, news]         [science, art, business]
2         [news]  [sport, science, art, business]
3      [science]     [sport, news, art, business]
```